# JavaScript/AppsScript Google Sheets: floating point arithmetic / precision

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have read a lot about JavaScript floating point arithmetic and this being the reason why some numbers have rounding problems or big numbers calculations have precision problems in JavaScript - and therfore the same problems occur in Google Apps Scrips as well, because they are written in JS.

But what I still don't understand is the following: If I have this Google Apps Script:

```
function myFunction() {
  let myNumber = -9.0027;
  return [myNumber];
}
```

And start the debugger with a breakpoint at the "return"-line in Google Scrips then the debugger shows me that the value of myNumber is

`myNumber: -9.002700000000001`

My current understanding of that additional "1" at the end is, that the representation of this number in memory is not big enough to show the precise number. Therefore JS needs to slightly change/modify/round the number and that is what we see with the "1" at the end.

But now I tested what I can see when I execute this function in Google Sheets:

`=myFunction()`

The result of that however is:

`-9,002700000000000000000000000000`

That tells me, that there must be a correct memory representation of this number existing even within Google Apps Script JS. So this doesn't fit with my first thought.

So maybe someone can help me understand why the JS debugger in Google Apps Script is not able to represent the correct number to me (even though it must exist somewhere in memory) but the Google Sheet does display the correct and precise number? I'm confused ....

Many thanks.

I used code and debugger in Google Script JS and Google Sheets and don't understand the differences.

Comment: how are you getting `9,002700000000000000000000000000`? Are you calling `toString` method

Comment: @adiga no. I'm just calling the function in a cell of Google sheets like this:  "=myFunction()"

Comment: @adiga Let me say it this way. I used the button in Google Sheets to display more digits. And then I can see the number with that many zeros. But it's definitely much longer than what I can see in the debugger.

Answer (score -1):

Debug informs that it has more numbers than it can display in errors.
Nothing can be done about it.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. Why should the debugger alter the number if there is no need for that? It could just display the original number -9.0027  . It's complete like that. And that is usually the way all other value are displayed as well. E.g.   x=-1.5

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).